# DocumentRoot always defaults to /var/www/html and cannot change it

Tags: php, apache, vagrant, document-root, puphpet

I've set up a Virtual host using PuPHPet (Vagrant-Puppet-PHP) Apparently PuPHPet creates a default site for me with this configuration `10-default_vhost_80.conf`

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName default

   ## Vhost docroot
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

   ## Directories, there should at least be a declaration for /var/www/html

   <Directory "/var/www/html">
     Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted

     <FilesMatch "\.php$">
       Require all granted
       SetHandler proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000
     </FilesMatch>

   </Directory>

   ## Logging
   ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/default_vhost_80_error.log"
   ServerSignature Off
   CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/default_vhost_80_access.log" combined
 </VirtualHost>
```

And I've created this site config `site_dev.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName site.dev

 ## Vhost docroot
 DocumentRoot "/var/www/web"

 ## Directories, there should at least be a declaration for /var/www/web

 <Directory "/var/www/web">
   Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted

   <FilesMatch "\.php$">
     Require all granted
     SetHandler proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000

   </FilesMatch>

 </Directory>

 ## Logging
 ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/av_0rjxvm6sfxhm_error.log"
 ServerSignature Off
 CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/av_0rjxvm6sfxhm_access.log" combined

 ## Server aliases
 ServerAlias www.site.dev

 ## SetEnv/SetEnvIf for environment variables
 SetEnv APP_ENV dev
</VirtualHost>
```

The default config is `apache2.conf`

```
 ServerName "local.puphpet"
 ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"
 PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
 Timeout 120
 KeepAlive Off
 MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
 KeepAliveTimeout 15

 User www-data
 Group www-data

 AccessFileName .htaccess
 <FilesMatch "^\.ht">
     Require all denied
 </FilesMatch>

 <Directory />
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride None
 </Directory>


 HostnameLookups Off
 ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
 LogLevel warn
 EnableSendfile Off

 #Listen 80


 Include "/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.load"
 Include "/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/*.conf"
 Include "/etc/apache2/ports.conf"

 LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
 LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
 LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
 LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

 IncludeOptional "/etc/apache2/conf.d/*.conf"
 IncludeOptional "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*"
```

I've already disabled the `10-default_vhost_80` and reloaded apache however my DocumentRoot still points to `/var/www/html/` am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I did was made the `/var/www/html` into a symbolic link and point to `/var/www/web`. This solved my problem for the mean time.

**UPDATE**
I found another problem using the solution above, it affects the `xdebug` configuration I have and the process cannot find the files in `/var/www/web` because it is looking for the files in the symbolic link `/var/www/html`. So
another work around is modify the `10-default_vhost_80.conf` file and change `/var/www/html` to `/var/www/web` manually and restart the server. So far so good.

**UPDATE 2**
So the proper fix is that you need to make sure that the `Directory Block` is filled up in the `puphpet` configurator and it would produce the `directories` section you see in the `yaml` file below. I think this is due to that update to `apache 2.4` why this needs to be done.

So I ended up with this `config.yaml`

```
    av_s4zfpb2muecx:
        servername: sandbox.dev
        serveraliases:
            - www.sandbox.dev
        docroot: /var/www/web
        port: '80'
        setenv:
            - 'APP_ENV dev'
        custom_fragment: ''
        ssl: '0'
        ssl_cert: ''
        ssl_key: ''
        ssl_chain: ''
        ssl_certs_dir: ''
        ssl_protocol: ''
        ssl_cipher: ''
        directories:
            avd_e84h116m6dg3:
                path: /var/www/web
                options:
                    - Indexes
                    - FollowSymlinks
                    - MultiViews
                allow_override:
                    - All
                require:
                    - 'all granted'
                custom_fragment: ''
                files_match:
                    avdfm_e84h116m6dg3:
                        path: \.php$
                        sethandler: 'proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000'
                        custom_fragment: ''
                        provider: filesmatch
                provider: directory
```

Also if you see that your `PHP` files aren't parsing make sure to include that `files_match` section. It's not added by the `puphpet` configurator automatically so you need to add that in via hard code.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the docroot path and the directories paths to /var/www/www, as below. This still creates the html folder, but serves from the www folder which is what I want.

```
vhosts:
    av_dpp1xawpupht:
        servername: mysite.local
        serveraliases:
            - www.mysite.local
        docroot: /var/www/www
        port: '80'
        setenv:
            - 'APPLICATION_ENV development'
        custom_fragment: ''
        ssl: '0'
        ssl_cert: ''
        ssl_key: ''
        ssl_chain: ''
        ssl_certs_dir: ''
        ssl_protocol: ''
        ssl_cipher: ''
        directories:
            avd_rtgzo3tlwbux:
                path: /var/www/www
                options:
                    - Indexes
                    - FollowSymlinks
                    - MultiViews
                allow_override:
                    - All
                require:
                    - 'all granted'
                custom_fragment: ''
                files_match:
                    avdfm_q9dzltiv10d5:
                        path: \.php$
                        sethandler: 'proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000'
                        custom_fragment: ''
                        provider: filesmatch
                provider: directory
```

Comment: I also did this but using `/var/www/web` instead but still Puphpet creates the `10-default_vhost_80` config which points to `/var/www/html` I think that is the reason why it's pointing to the `html` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this issue.

For me, it was caused by the `servername` property in my `puphpet/config.yaml` file not matching the domain listed in my `hosts` file.

I ensured the ip address and domain specified in my `puphpet/config.yaml` file:

```
vm:
    network:
        private_network: 192.168.56.199
                  .
                  .
                  .

vhosts:
    av_9kfiq4m95oac:
        servername: mysite.dev
        serveraliases:
            - www.mysite.dev
```

matched what I specified in my `hosts` file:

```
192.168.56.199 mysite.dev www.mysite.dev
```

Oh, and don't forget to run `vagrant provision` after making changes to the `puphpet/config.yaml` file (that's caught me out a few times).